# Using WCF IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest to change the ContentType of a request

Tags: wcf

I have an WCF web service where a client uses an incorrect content-type.  This in turn leads to an error.

I was hoping to be able to intercept the incoming request on the server side and fix the header so that the request can be processed.  I attempted to do so by implementing a IDispatchMessageInspector and having the AfterReceiveRequest modify the content-type as follows:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty req = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties["httpRequest"];
    req.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "correct content type");
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to do the trick.  The modified content type is not picked up.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have to create a copy of the message, do your processing on it and then set the `ref request` parameter to the new message. I know this is a bit counter intuitive, but there you are.

To copy the message you use it's `CreateBufferedCopy` method.

Comment: OP is trying to change the *headers*, not the message body.  I don't think you need to do anything with the body to change/add headers.

Comment: Alas ... that did not solve the problem.  There is absolutely no doubt that the AfterReceiveRequest method was called and no doubt that the modified Message has the correct content-type set)   Is it possible that the content-type needs to be set a different (or additional) way?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like :

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "correct content type";
```

(from [Is it possible to set ContentType for a WCF WebGet method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239790/is-it-possible-to-set-contenttype-for-a-wcf-webget-method))

Also, this post ([Copy HTTP request / response headers from a call to a HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489057/copy-http-request-response-headers-from-a-call-to-a-httpwebrequest)) 
talk about restriction on some headers (I did not research it in more depth):

> However, understand that some headers are **restricted, and cannot be
>   modified freely**. These are:
>   
>  . . .
>   
>   **Content-Length**

Comment: Still no luck. (According to the post you referenced, the contenttype cannot be modified)